# How do I change the numbers in a cell to the word 'Bus' in Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame that has both numbers and text in the same column, all of which are of an object type. How do I convert only the numbers in the cell to `int` while the text remains as an object?

I tried using the `pandas function >> pd.to_numeric(df, errors='ignore')`
but only the columns with no text gets converted to float. the rest remains as an object

```
27      72      27      72      None    None    None    None    
34      34  None    None    None    None    None    None    
MRT     MRT     None    None    None    None    None    None    
MRT     MRT     None    None    None    None    None    None    
MRT     MRT     None    None    None    None    None    None    
121     195     121     195     None    None    None    None    
175     147     147     175     None    None    None    None     
33      33      None    None    None    None    None    None    





Bus     Bus     Bus     Bus     None    None    None    None    
Bus     Bus     None    None    None    None    None    None    
MRT     MRT     None    None    None    None    None    None    
MRT     MRT     None    None    None    None    None    None    
MRT     MRT     None    None    None    None    None    None    
Bus     Bus     Bus     Bus     None    None    None    None    
Bus     Bus     Bus     Bus     None    None    None    None    
Bus     Bus     None    None    None    None    None    None
```

Answer (score 2):

IIUC using `to_numeric` with `mask`

```
yourdf=df.mask(df.apply(pd.to_numeric,errors='coerce',axis=1).notnull(),'BUS')
yourdf
Out[631]: 
    27   72  27.1  72.1  None None.1 None.2 None.3
0  BUS  BUS  None  None  None   None   None   None
1  MRT  MRT  None  None  None   None   None   None
2  MRT  MRT  None  None  None   None   None   None
3  MRT  MRT  None  None  None   None   None   None
4  BUS  BUS   BUS   BUS  None   None   None   None
5  BUS  BUS   BUS   BUS  None   None   None   None
6  BUS  BUS  None  None  None   None   None   None
```

Comment: ha, my solution is almost exact as yours. One comment: get rid of  `axis=1` makes `apply` works on columns, hence vectorized.

Comment: @QuangHoang ha , nice solution then :-) and thank you for the hint

Comment: also `df.where(df.apply(pd.to_numeric,errors='corece').isnull(),'Bus')`

Comment: Worked flawlessly. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2):

If your real data look like that, i.e. contains no strings like `12.3`, you can try convert it to `to_numeric` and fill non-na with 'Bus'

```
df[df.apply(pd.to_numeric, 
            args={'errors':'ignore'})
     .notnull()] = 'Bus'
```

Test data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[12, 'None', None],
                   'b':[23, 'MRT', None]})
```

gives:

```
    a       b
0   Bus     Bus
1   None    MRT
2   None    None
```

Answer (score 0):

In dataframe, you can use replace()

```
dataframe.replace(old_value, new_value)
```

like this